# What does "could be to get offended" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Mia: This sounds like you actually have somethin' to say.
>
> Vincent: Well, well, I do. I do. But you have to promise not to be
> offended.
>
> Mia: No, no. You can't promise somethin' like that. I have no idea
> what you're  gonna ask me. You can ask me what you're gonna ask me,
> and my natural response **could be to get offended**. Then, through no
> fault of my own, I would have broken  my promise.

What does "could be to get offended" mean?

"could be to get offended" means that a possible outcome of what he says would be Mia getting offended?

Source: Pulp Fiction 1994

Comment: Mia's natural response could be, she says, to get (become) offended.

Comment: The words "could be" are copulative, just like the word "is". This is a conditional form of "the response is to get offended". The copulative verb equates "response" and "to get offended". So, yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Try replacing "could" with "might" and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

All of the following sentences are grammatically correct and equivalent in meaning:

> 1. If you ask me a question, my natural response could be to get offended.
> 2. If you ask me a question, I might become offended after hearing your question.
> 3. If you ask me a question, your question might make me feel angry.
> 4. If you ask me a question, I could get mad at you.
> 5. If you ask me a question, it is possible that I might react emotionally.
> 6. If you ask me a question, it is possible that it might produce a reaction of anger in myself.